# Windows Certificate Authority request form submit failure

Tags: windows, ca

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Standalone Root CA setup to issue authentication certificates when requested via the certrqma.asp page. This page has been modified to only show a small number of fields required but no configuration has been changed over the default and has worked fine in the past, however, recently (Not exactly sure when) the page simply won't submit the request.

I can see errors via the console in both IE and Chrome but the user feedback on form submission is to display the message:

> This page has not finished loading yet. Please wait a few seconds and try again.

- IE Console: SCRIPT5009: 'GetCSPList' is undefined - certrqma.asp (1523,3)
- Chrome Console: Uncaught ReferenceError: loadXEnroll is not defined at postLoad (certrqm.asp:997) & at onload (certrqma.asp:9)

My ASP coding is non-existent and am feeling my way along but at least found the above so hoping it's useful detail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, this is a direct result of Microsoft disabling, by default, the execution of VBScript in IE11 onwards. This was changed in the August 2019 Windows Security Update and has been planned since early 2017: [An update on disabling VBScript in Internet Explorer 11](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/02/update-disabling-vbscript-internet-explorer-windows-7-8/)

VBScript can easily be re-enabled in IE using one of the methods in [Option to disable VBScript execution in Internet Explorer for Internet Zone and Restricted Sites Zone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012494/option-to-disable-vbscript-execution-in-internet-explorer-for-internet) but compromising security is not something we should have to ask clients to do in order to use this as intended.

I thought the Windows 2019 Server version of this form would be coded differently to address this seeing as disabling it has been in the pipeline for so long but is not the case as 2019 Server Certificate Services Web Enrollment still requires VBScript in order to use this form.